# how to change value of tiny int on mysql through vb

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

[this is the code im using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WInt1.png)hello guys i have been working on my thesis and these is my problem, I dont know the code to change the value of tinyint (1 and 0) in mysql workbench, through vb , any suggestions for code? im using vb 2012. Thanks in advance guys

[how to change those 0 into 1 using vb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiJt9.png)

Comment: Generally `tinyint` is an alias for Boolean in MySQL. So, `myBoolVar = Not myBoolVar`?  Its not real clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: ohhh okay, what im trying to do is , for example you choose a room then the value of the room in mysql will be 1 because it is occupied. if not it will remain 0. what code can do that in vb?

Comment: Please show the code you are using - it will provide much more clarity than trying to describe it.  I have no idea what you are working with DataTable? POCO? Simple Vars? DGV?

Comment: *just uploaded a photo :))

Comment: I know what SQL WorkBench looks like - if you want to change the value from VB Code, you need to show how you are using it in VB.  As I said, I have no idea how you are using the data - or is that the question: *how to get MySQL data into a VB app*?

Comment: i uploaded the code im using, please check it . thanks man

Comment: a) always post *the code*, not *pictures* of the code; people will Downvote you for it. b) you are not including the isBusy field in the SQL, so I guess you want to change the value for that room when they pick it? c) You probably *do* want ID in the SQL so you can more easily update  d) You should be disposing of the Command and Connection objects - use `Using` blocks to automate that.

Comment: Also, your logic is flawed if you are trying to only show available Buildings (oddly, not rooms).  Your combobox (?) is going to show all, not all *available*: `SELECT Id, BuildingNo WHERE isBusy = 0`. of course since there are only 2 bldgs, your hospital (?) can only service 2 patients at a time, so the code should handle that situation.